# Wan ip always 0.0.0.0 after set bridge mode

Tags: networking, bridge, wide-area-network, modem

I try to set my my modem(unnanti A-300M) as Bridge Mode (set eventhing as a default), After getting wan addr is 0.0.0.0.

[Easy for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS5fR.png)

**note**: unnanti A-300M = Modem + Router

Comment: When in bridge mode, your modem does not have IP addresses on the interfaces, it is a bridge. Bridges work at layer-2, but IP addresses and routing work at layer-3.